# It cannot find global modules

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, npm

I have installed the last npm 5.5.1 on my Ubuntu local. I installed globally the modules that I frequently use (like express, etc.).
In this way in my package.json I leave "dependencies" blank and npm goes looking for modules in the right directory (`/usr/lib/node_modules/`). 
This worked with my last npm 3.10.10 but now something seems is changed.
When I try to run a app I got: "Cannot find module express".

Answer (score 0):

The express executable file is provided by express-generator in Ubuntu 14.04. To install it globally run `sudo npm install -g express-generator`

The easiest way to globally install an up-to-date version of the Express Node.js web application framework in Ubuntu 16.04 and later is from the default Ubuntu repositories using the command:

```
sudo apt install node-express node-express-generator
```

The  express.js file is installed to `/usr/lib/nodejs/express/express.js` in the same directory as package.json which is installed to `/usr/lib/nodejs/express/package.json`

The above command installs node-express version 4.1.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. The latest version of Express at [the official Express website](https://expressjs.com/) is 4.16.1, so the version of Express from the default Ubuntu repositories is almost as up-to-date as the latest version.

Comment: I don't want create a node_modules folder every time I create a project (in local)